# and operator on Python lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I've found some really strange behavior in Python. 
One of my students made some kind of mistake trying to find elements which belong to two lists, he wrote:

```
list1 and list2
```

The strange behavior is that no error is fired by Python 3!
`list1 and list2` actually has got a value which is `list2`.

Is there any known reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` simply evaluates the truthness of the two values provided. 
If the first is `True` (see `bool(list1)`) the second is evaluated and returned. If the first argument is `False` (e.g `[] and list2`) its value is returned immediately.

In the [documentation on Boolean Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) the rationale for this behavior is stated clearly:

> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather *return the last evaluated argument*. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Note that this behavior *isn't found* with `not` which, instead, returns a `True`/`False` value based on the argument provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I didn't understand.

Comment: You're welcome @Coulombeau. Always peek in the Python Docs for behaviors like this, it usually is hidden somewhere in there :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask `list1 and list2`, python calls the `__bool__` on `list1` and `list2`. Since `[]` evaluates to `False`, and a non-empty list evaluates to `True`, `and` looks at `list1` and `list2` in turn until it finds an empty list (or it looks at all the lists, if an empty list is never found).

Finally, the `and` expression evaluates to either that empty list that makes the `and` fail, or the last list in the comparison. This is why you get `list2` back as the value.

Interestingly, you can use this behavior to your advantage to set default values:

```
def func(arg=None):
    arg = arg or [5]  # now, [5] is the default value of arg
```

This is practically the same as doing:

```
def func(arg=None):
    if arg is None:
        arg = [5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well , if they both have values then the "if list1 and list2:" should return True and it will continue to the next line in the code.
Python3 considers True if a variable is different then None or 0.
Example:

```
a = 1
if a: #This will be True since a is different then None or 0
    print("Works")
>>> Works

b = 0
if b:
    print("Works")
>>>
This one returned nothing because b is 0 wich means that the "if b" will return False.
```

Also , it will return True on lists if the list has atleast 1 element in it.